# Change Marker and Color of regression line/data matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have created 2 linear regression models and I have plotted them, but they both get colored red and have x for the marker.

How can I change one of the fitted lines color and marker?
I've tried two ways

```matlab
mdl_2 = fitlm(bbb, aaa);
p = plot(mdl_2, 'og'); % Gives an error since 'og' isn't expected as a parameter
```

and

```
p.Color='green';
p.Marker='o';
```

Both give errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

To set line properties you can use the following:

```
p(1).Color = "green"
```

**Explanation**
Plotting a linear regression models obtained with fitlm returns a plot with three visible lines:

- Data
- Fit
- Confidence bounds

Therefore when using the expression

```
    p=plot(mdl_2)
```

p contains a Line array. You can access each line using indexing, therefore p(1) access the "Data" field.

As you made clear in your question you already know how to set line properties, but for the sake of completeness and future readers i post the link of the official [MATLAB page](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.line-properties.html). In the page there are all the possible settings.